# pass variable from a function to a request in laravel

Tags: controller, request, laravel-5.1

Hello i am having an issue trying to understand laravel, i am trying to pass data from one function to a request to save in the database and i keep getting this error: Attempt to assign property of non-object

```
public function active()
{
    $activity = str_random(25);

    $result = purchase::where('active', '=', $activity)->get()->first();
    if(!$result){

        return $activity;
    }
}

public function store(AddOrder $request)
{
    $user = new Bid();
    $user = $request->all();
    $user->activate = $this->active();

    return $user;
}
```

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Sorry figured it out

changed

```
public function store(AddOrder $request)
{
$user = new Bid();
$user = $request->all();
$user->activate = $this->active();

return $user;
}
```

to

```
public function store(AddOrder $request)
{
$user = new Bid();
$user = $request->all();
$user['activate'] = $this->active();

return $user;
}
```